# How to hide application name in URL thru Apache?

Tags: apache, tomcat, web, jboss, server

Am using Apache web server infront of JBoss App server.
Have made all the changes that land me on log in page of application without entering application name in URL.for ex i enter http://IP/ it redirects to http://IP/App/login.jsp, work perfect.

But i dont want my application name to be visible.I want to my user to redirect to URL as http://IP/login.jsp when they enter http://IP/. 'App' to be invisible in the URL. Please help me how can i achieve the same. Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Install your app on JBoss on root context, and then it will be served without app name in url. How to do it depends in details from JBoss version, but you can try by creating `jboss-web.xml` file with context definition:

   ```
   <context>/</context>
   ```
2. You can from example use `mod_proxy` as balance in Apache, and configure proper redirection. Place in virtual server definition smth like that:

   ```
   ProxyPass / http://IP/App
   ProxyPassReverse / http://IP/App
   ```